# What are the projective dimensions of big fraction fields?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-resolution

Let $A$ be an integral domain, $B$ is its fraction field. Can the projective dimension of the $A$-module $B$ be greater than $1$? This surely cannot happen if the spectrum of $A$ is countable (since then the presentation of $B$ as a countable direct limit of $A$-modules gives a length $1$ projective resolution for it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this can happen. See for example https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118801622